# AJAX Cascading with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I used the below method for doing `Async` postback using `AJAX`. This works fine on clicking `submit`. But i would like to know, is that possible to call various `ActionMethod`s in a controller via `AJAX`.

I would like to implement something like cascading dropdown. How to call different `ActionMethod` via `AJAX` on dropdown value change?

Here is the code which call only one `ActionMethod` on submitting form.

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var options = new AjaxOptions()
{
    Url = Url.Action("Index", "City"),
    LoadingElementId = "saving",
    LoadingElementDuration = 2000,
    Confirm = "Are you sure you want to submit?"
};  
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(options))
{
    <div id="saving">Loading...</div>
    @Html.DropDownList("Countries",ViewBag.Countries as SelectList)<input type="submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new [] 
                                                    { 
                                                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "US",Value = "1" } 
                                                    };

    ViewBag.Countries = selectListItems;

    return View();
}

public ActionResult GetState(string countryId)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new[] 
                                                { 
                                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "Tennesse", Value = "1" },
                                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "Newyork", Value = "2" }
                                                };

        return View();        
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cascading-DropDownList-in-833683f9), and also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12648861/1551730)

Comment: please comment on answer if any problem still exist or accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question `"is that possible to call various ActionMethods in a controller via AJAX"` is a big yes. You may call any action method from your controller through Ajax though the only result generated depends on various things like whether you send a view or partial view or JSON result.

for your next question :

I will be posting some codes

`Controller.cs`

```
public JsonResult getCity(string country)
    {
        var temp = (from cntry in db.Table3.OrderBy(s => s.country)
                    where (string.Compare(cntry.country, country) == 0)
                    select cntry.city).ToList();
        return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`View`

```
<h1>
Countries</h1>
<select name="countries" class="combo">
<option value=""></option>

@{
    foreach (var t in (List<string>)ViewBag.countries)
    {
    <option value=@t>@t</option>
    }
}
 </select>
<h1>
State</h1>
<select name="city" class="combo2">
</select>
<div id="tese">
</div>
@*
The following jquery code finds the selected option from country dropdown 
and then sends an ajax call to the Home/getcity method 
and finally populate it to the city dropdown 
*@
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedValue);
    $.get("/Home/getcity", { country: selectedValue }, function (data) {
        $("#tese").html(data);
        $(".combo2").html("<option value = \"\"></option>")
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $(".combo2").append("<option value = \"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>");
        });
        $(".combo2").html()
    });
});
</script>
```

This will show a dropdown of countries list. Once a country is selected it will render a new dropdown of city list

Answer (score 1):

```
public JsonResult getCity(string country)
    {
        var temp = (from cntry in db.Table3.OrderBy(s => s.country)
                    where (string.Compare(cntry.country, country) == 0)
                    select cntry.city).ToList();
        return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
<h1>
Countries</h1>
<select name="countries" class="combo">
<option value=""></option>

@{
    foreach (var t in (List<string>)ViewBag.countries)
    {
    <option value=@t>@t</option>
    }
}
 </select>
<h1>
State</h1>
<select name="city" class="combo2">
</select>
<div id="tese">
</div>
@*
The following jquery code finds the selected option from country dropdown 
and then sends an ajax call to the Home/getcity method 
and finally populate it to the city dropdown 
*@
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedValue);
    $.get("/Home/getcity", { country: selectedValue }, function (data) {
        $("#tese").html(data);
        $(".combo2").html("<option value = \"\"></option>")
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $(".combo2").append("<option value = \"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>");
        });
        $(".combo2").html()
    });
});
</script>
```