# passing multiple params to a mvc controller from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a couple of params to an mvc controller from jquery but the method is receiving null values even though the debugger shows the val() of both controls in the browser debugger are present.

```
$(function () {
    $('#Counties').cascade({
        data: JSON.stringify('{state: ' +  $("#States").val() + ', county: ' + $("#Counties").val() + '}'),
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")',
        childSelect: $('#Cities')
    });
});
```

[image]

I tried both methods in the answers below one with JSON.stringify and without. The values are still coming across as null

[image]

Here is the updated code. I read on another post that I may need to write a Route for the method. I added that but that didn't work either

```
$(function () {
    $('#Counties').cascade({
        data: {state: $("#States").val(), county: $("#Counties").val()},
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")',
        childSelect: $('#Cities')
    });
});


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCities(string state, string county)
{
    var cities = _carrierRouteAssignmentRepository.GetCities(state, county);
    return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetCities",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{state}/{county}",
    defaults: new { controller = "CarrierRouteAssignments", action = "GetCities", state = UrlParameter.Optional, county = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

running fiddler I see the request going out as

```
/CarrierRouteAssignments/GetCities?undefined=LOS+ANGELES
```

which is incorrect

Comment: Try to pass the actually javascript object to `JSON.stringify` instead of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what the problem was. I was using the helper method from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724581/how-to-populate-a-html-dropdownlist-after-selecting-another-html-dropdownlist) and didn't look there for the problem. I also didn't post this in the original question. As you will notice the helper method only takes 1 param and that is the one that is passed to the helper. I will either have to expand this helper or just bypass it for the last dropdownlist cascade. Thanks for all the input. It did clear up an issue.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cascade = function (options) {
        var defaults = {};
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                var params = {};
                params[opts.paramName] = selectedValue;
                $.getJSON(opts.url, params, function (items) {
                    opts.childSelect.empty();
                    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                        opts.childSelect.append(
                        $('<option/>')
                            .attr('value', item)
                            .text(item)
                    );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a object to `JSON.stringify()` method, Currently you are passing string

Use

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    state: $("#States").val() , 
    county: $("#Counties").val() 
}),
```

instead of

```
data: JSON.stringify('{state: ' +  $("#States").val() + ', county: ' + $("#Counties").val() + '}'),
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
$(function () {
    $('#Counties').cascade({
         data:{ state: $("#States").val() ,  county: $("#Counties").val() },
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")',
        childSelect: $('#Cities')
    });
});
```