# How to bind data to Html.DropDownList when I click on it - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET MVC dropdown and binding data to it. Data already I have in model which I got from API call.

```
@Html.DropDownList("productddl", Model.selectListItems, "--Select--")
```

What I need is to bind data to dropdown when I click on it. I want to make API call when user click on it and bind the data.

What event do I need to use, How can I do that ?

Comment: You will make use `ajax` call to bind data when the user clicks on the dropdown. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084568/populate-dropdownlist-using-ajax-mvc-4) should give you a good starting point

Comment: @Izzy - There I am able to Change event which gets fired when we select something from ddl. I need event name when we click on ddl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bind data to dropdown when I click on it.

```
<div>
  @Html.DropDownList("DesignDropdown", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "" } })
</div>
```

Below is JavaScript code in the same page inside `<script>` tag

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetDesign", "Design")'; // url/api to get data
var ddl = $('#DesignDropdown'); //get ddl instance
$('#DesignDropdown').focus(function () {

    $.post(url, {id: designId}, function (response) {
        ddl.empty(); //clear if already data there
        ddl.append($('<option></option>').text("--Select--").val("")); //first item as --Select--
        $.each(response, function (index, item) {
            ddl.append($('<option></option>').text(item.Name).val(item.DesignId)); //bind api result to ddl
        });
    });

    $('#DesignDropdown').blur();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET runs in the server and it responds to HTTP requests. Altering a `select` list does not trigger a HTTP request, it is a purely browser based operation. You can write some JavaScript code which listens to the client side event that this raises (likely [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)), and then write your own code to perform a request to the server.